# Network Interface seems to idle for 0.5 seconds before sending a message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I am currently looking into what happens when connecting to a Wi-Fi network, and it seems that there is a period of ~0.5 seconds between wpa_supplicant claims to be connected, and until a ping message is transmitted.

What is going on in this period? I've taken a look at various logs and cannot find any indication of what is happening.

Example:

- Ping is running in background on Wi-Fi interface
- wpa_supplicant receives a 'disconnect' followed by a 'reconnect' command, and starts connecting to a specified network after scanning.
- After a small period, wpa_supplicant claims to be associated and connected to the network (indicated by the "State: GROUP_HANDSHAKE -> COMPLETED" in the log). Likewise, the IP address is configured as I was connected to the same network a moment ago.
- 0.8 seconds later, the first ping is sent on the interface.

I used tcpdump to determine when the ping request was sent after the reconnect command, and except for the 4-way handshake i can only see a couple multicast messages just after wpa_supplicant finished connecting.

The ping command I used was:

```
sudo ping -i 0.05 -I wlan0 -D 192.168.18.70
```

I am using an Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 network card on Linux 20.04.1 LTS. Network Manager is disabled/configured to ignore this specific interface.

Comment: Please include the exact `ping` command you are running while doing a reconnection.

Comment: I edited the post to include this now